# Android OpenglES change camera with pan gesture using lookat function

Tags: android, opengl-es

I rotate camera using OpenGLES build-in function lookat. When user pan the screen, they are able to see the object 360 degree. However, when I calculate the view Matrix, this is something wrong with the vectors calculate...
currently, it is not working, when pan the screen, the object will disappear, because mForward = mForward.rotate(dy, mRight.x,mRight.y,mRight.z).nor(); will make the mForward turn to (0,0,0), and other vector will be 0,0,0 as well. I expect people could look left and right(360), up and down(180), like the google street view. That is rotate the mTarget horizontally 360 degree, vertivally 180 degree...

the vector set up:

```
public Vector3 mLocation = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f);
public Vector3 mTarget = new Vector3(0f,0f,-3f);
public Vector3 mUp = new Vector3(0f,1f,0f);
```

the lookat function:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0,
                mLocation.x,mLocation.y,mLocation.z,
                mTarget.x,mTarget.y,mTarget.z,
                mUp.x,mUp.y,mUp.z);
```

the touch event:

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();
        mForward = mRenderer.mTarget.sub(mRenderer.mLocation).nor();
        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float dx = x - mPreviousX;
                float dy = y - mPreviousY;
//                //        To rotate left or right, rotate the forward around up and then use a cross product between forward and up to get the right vector.
                mForward = mForward.rotate(dx, mRenderer.mUp.x,mRenderer.mUp.y,mRenderer.mUp.z).nor();
                mRight = mForward.crs(mRenderer.mUp).nor();
//                //        To rotate up or down, rotate forward vector around right vector and use a cross product between the right and forward to get the new up vector.
                mForward = mForward.rotate(dy, mRight.x,mRight.y,mRight.z).nor();
                mRenderer.mUp = mRight.crs(mForward).nor();

                mRenderer.mTarget = mRenderer.mLocation.add(mForward);

                requestRender();
        }
        mPreviousX = x;
        mPreviousY = y;
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: What is your current result and what is the expected result?

Comment: currently, it is not working, when pan the screen, the object will disappear, because mForward = mForward.rotate(dy, mRight.x,mRight.y,mRight.z).nor(); will make the mForward turn to (0,0,0), and other vector will be 0,0,0 as well. I expect people could look left and right(360), up and down(180), like the google street view. That is rotate the mTarget horizontally 360 degree, vertivally 180 degree... @Matic Oblak

Comment: Put a breakpoint in touch method and check which is the first line that produces an incorrect result. Is mForward already at 0 when computing it from forward and position?

Comment: Well, when run the line :  mRenderer.mTarget = mRenderer.mLocation.add(mForward); everything turn to 0,0,0, before that, every thing has its value...@ Matic Oblak

Comment: Is there a bug in the add method? Or do those 2 vectors have such values that the result is zero?

Comment: before call vUp = (vRight.crs(vForward)).nor(), the mForward already equals mRight. I think because when assign a vector using call a function on another one, at the same time, the value of the vector which calls function will be changed as well... @ Matic Oblak

Comment: When I change the add and crs function, make it add or crs 2 vectors, fix the problems. Now, I define the upvectore,  instead of use mRenderer.mUp = mRight.crs(mForward).nor(); I use mRenderer.mUp = new Vector3 (0f,1f,0f);, to make sure user can see vertically 180 degree...The screen fliped when the forward.y alomost = 1 or -1 and the users still pan the object ... Do you know the problem? @Matic Oblak

Comment: If you have a fixed up the way you described then you need to limit the forward vector not to be parallel to up. But for that case it is best to simply hold the 2 angles and modify those on touch events, then use trigonometry to compute the 2 vectors from the angles.

Comment: Not really understand " hold the 2 angles and modify those on touch events, then use trigonometry to compute the 2 vectors from the angles", could you give an example? Thanks a lot~~~@ Matic Oblak

Comment: You may define the rotation with 2 angles for horizontal and vertical rotation (say ax and ay) then on touch events these are increased by dx and dy from touch events. Then to get forward you use trigonometry such as x=cos(ay)*cos(ax), y=cos(ay)*sin(ax), z=sin(ay) which are spherical coordinates. Them ax can go to infinity but ay goes from -180 to 180 degrees.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!,, is this right?
                ax = + dx;
                ay = + dy; 
                vForward.x = (float)Math.cos(ay) * (float)Math.cos(ax);
                vForward.y = (float)Math.cos(ay)* (float)Math.sin(ax);
                vForward.z = (float)Math.sin(ay);
                vForward.nor();
                vTarget = vTarget.add2Vector(vForward,vLocation); @ Matic Oblak

Comment: ax += dx, ay += dy and if(ay>PI/2 -0.01) ay = PI/2 -0.01; else if(ay<-PI/2 +0.01) ay = ay=-PI/2 +0.01;

Comment: well, not working well, I think it is pan x well change y, pan y will change x, So I go back to adjust the rotate vector way, I adjust vforward,y, but when the vforward = the max value, the vofrward x and z still changed,, so the target will still rotate horizontally.. any idea how to adjust x and z? here is the y adjust: if (vForward.y > 1f - 0.01f){
                    vForward.y = 1f - 0.01f;
                }else if (vForward.y < -1f + 0.01f){
                    vForward.y = -1f + 0.01f;
                },  @ Matic Oblak

Comment: You should probably look for the correct equations but try this:
vForward.x = (float)Math.cos(ay) * (float)Math.sin(ax);
        vForward.y = (float)Math.sin(ay);
        vForward.z = (float)Math.cos(ay)* (float)Math.cos(ax);